# Unable to add a path correctly

Tags: 14.04, command-line, paths

I have a folder:

```
/usr/src/arm-linux-3.3/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin
```

I can execute a command from here(I had to install the ia32-libs equivalenet on ubuntu 14.04)

Now I tried to add the path in the .profile. The path is being added correctly. However when I try to execute it from the terminal it keeps telling me command not found. Why is this?

My .profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/arm-linux-3.3/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin
```

echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/src/arm-linux-3.3/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin
```

Comment: Add the *correctly added path* to your question

Comment: @A.B.Edited the question

Comment: Did you re-login after adding to `.profile`? What does `echo $PATH` output?

Comment: It gives me the correct path

Comment: does `export PATH="<your-dir>:$PATH"` work? This should put your custom directory at the beginning of `$PATH`

Comment: When you say you can execute a command "from here" do you mean (1) by prepending the full path or (2) by cd'ing to the directory and then executing `./command`? If the latter, then the issue may be that `./command` is expecting to find some libraries via a relative path such as `../lib`

Comment: Its the latter. But how do I fugre that you?

Answer (score 0):

The file `~/.profile` is being ignored by the shell if a file `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists. First check if these files exists. If not, this was not the problem.

Comment: The echo $PATH shows this is not the case

Comment: Yes you are right, too early for me. I can't replicate that error I even `mkdir` the path and put a perl script in it, but it works just fine here. I am out.

Comment: This is something very strange for me too